# SubQuery MS Access SQL Code Assistance Requested

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I get this syntax error

> (Missing Operator) in query expression 'Purchases.SUOM_Orders IN (SELECT COUNT(Purchases.SUOM_Orders) FROM Purchases WHERE Purchases.Order_Date>=DATE()-120) subQryCount

There may be other errors that the compiler has not progressed to yet but if you see anything, please correct. I appreciate your help.  Ignore the 'your text' parts.  I tried to get my code to post in the forum, which is the reason for those parts.

```
SELECT 
    Inventory.Item_No, Inventory.NDC, Pharmacy.NDC_Desc, 
    ROUND(Inventory.OH_Qty_EA / Pharmacy.McK_PackQty, 0) AS ‘McKesson_OH_Qty’,
    SUM(Purchases.SUOM_Orders / subQryCount.SUOM_Orders) * Pharmacy.Safecor_PackQty * 1.5 / Pharmacy.McK_PackQty AS 'Avg_Par', 
    SUM(Purchases.SUOM_Orders / subQryCount.SUOM_Orders) * Pharmacy.Safecor_PackQty * 1.5 - SUM(Inventory.OH_Qty_EA) / Pharmacy.McK_PackQty AS 'Avg_OrdQty'
FROM 
    (Inventory 
LEFT JOIN 
    Pharmacy ON Inventory.Item_No = Pharmacy.Item_No) 
LEFT JOIN 
    Purchases ON Pharmacy.Item_No = Purchases.Item_No
WHERE 
    Purchases.SUOM_Orders IN (SELECT COUNT(Purchases.SUOM_Orders) 
                              FROM Purchases
                              WHERE Purchases.Order_Date >= DATE() - 120) subQryCount
 GROUP BY 
     Purchases.Item_No ASC
 HAVING 
     Avg_OrdQty > 0;
```

Comment: Use brackets not apostrophes to delimit object names, including alias names: `AS [Avg_OrdQty]`. However, in this case because there are no spaces nor special characters, delimiters are not needed. Are you using Access query designer to build? Access is picky about parentheses in JOIN clauses. What you have doesn't look right for Access. Use the designer to get join clauses correct.

Comment: Field name subQryCount.SUOM_Orders is referenced in outer query but this field is not available to the outer query. SUOM_Orders is used in a Count() expression and no alias name is assigned to the expression. Perhaps need to assign allias and reference that in outer query.

Comment: I also tested assigning an alias table name as you have done with SQL nested within IN() function - doesn't work so disregard suggestion in previous comment. This WHERE clause doesn't make sense to me. Might be helpful to provide sample data and desired output as formatted text tables or post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.